# Postgresql Jdbc Prepared statement Query String with Single Quotes giving error

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm trying to run a query using jdbc but i'm having difficulty injecting values into the prepared statement. Here is a sample of what I was doing:

```
String queryString = "... WHERE location <@ box '((?, ?),(?, ?))' ..."
PreparedStatement ps = this.connection.prepareStatement(queryString);
ps.setDouble(1, x1);
ps.setDouble(2, y1);
ps.setDouble(3, x2);
ps.setDouble(4, y2);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

Which gives me this error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.
```

I think it thinks that the values in the single quotes are string literals and so it doesn't see the ? as parameters to inject.

Does anyone know how I could fix this? Or rather what else I should be looking to do?

Comment: The `?` is not recognized as a parameter inside single quotes by JDBC

Comment: Question marks in a string literal are just question marks in a string, not parameter markers.